# how to subtract values from json encoded array then pass into table

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

Below is my JSON encoded array. Here I want to subtract `is_completed` from `totaltasks` and show it as pending inside a table.

```
[{"totalstaff":"2","totaltasks":"2","is_completed":"1"}]
```

The code I am using is here

```
var data = $.parseJSON(report);
var the_table = '<table border="1"><tbody><tr style="text-align:center;"> 
<td>totalstaff</td><td>totaltasks</td> 
<td>completed</td><td>pending</td></tr>';

$.each(data, function (i) {
  $("#overlay").html( the_table +"<tr><td>" + 
  data[i].totalstaff + "</td><td>" + data[i].totaltasks + "</td><td>" + 
  data[i].is_completed + "</td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: Please take care when writing your questions; this was an unreadable mess before I edited it.

Comment: ok iam so sorry i want to subtract is_completed from 
    total tasks and show it as pending inside a table. how to do that can u please help me?

Comment: From the code itself, you already know how to get the values so you just need to use the subtraction operator...? Also, it appears you're creating a `table` with no closing tag on each iteration of the loop - I assume that's not intentional. Can you also please expand on what you mean by 'show it as pending'?

Comment: value of totaltasks is :2 and value of is_completed is: 1 so i want to subtract is_completed from totaltasks and return it as pending and show the whole in the form of a table

Comment: can any one please tell me how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe like this:

```js
 var data_str='[{"totalstaff":"2","totaltasks":"2","is_completed":"1"}]';
 var data=JSON.parse(data_str);
 if(data[0]){  //if length of data > 0
   var table=$('<table/>').attr('border', '1');
   var first_tr=$('<tr/>').css('text-align', 'center');
   var td=$('<td/>').text('totalstaff');
    first_tr.append(td);
   td=$('<td/>').text('totaltasks');
    first_tr.append(td);
   td=$('<td/>').text('completed');
    first_tr.append(td);
   td=$('<td/>').text('pending');
    first_tr.append(td);
   table.append(first_tr);

      for(var key in data){
          var tr=$('<tr/>');
          td=$('<td/>').text(data[key].totalstaff);
            tr.append(td);
          td=$('<td/>').text(data[key].totaltasks);
            tr.append(td);
          td=$('<td/>').text(data[key].is_completed);
            tr.append(td);
          td=$('<td/>').text(parseInt(data[key].totaltasks, 10) - parseInt(data[key].is_completed, 10));
            tr.append(td);
          table.append(tr);
      }

   $('body').append(table);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```